how to work with initializers inside UIView?
Good afternoon everyone.
Guys, tell me how it is possible to initialize a custom parameter in view?
I want to pass the variable currentMenuItem inside the SampleSkinsCollectionView class.
I just can’t understand how the initializer works inside IUView.
This parent View. I add class "SampleSkinsCollectionView".
final class MainSecondViewController: HeaderMenuViewController {

    // MARK: - Dependencies
    var iterator: IMainIterator?
    var handlerCardCellDelegate: IHandlerCellDelegate?

    // MARK: - Private properties
    private var currentMenuItem: MenuItem?
    private lazy var collectionCardSkins = SampleSkinsCollectionView()

    override init(delegate: IMenuDelegate, currentMenuItem: MenuItem) {
        super.init(delegate: delegate, currentMenuItem: currentMenuItem)
        self.currentMenuItem = currentMenuItem
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    // MARK: - Public methods
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupConfiguration()
        addUIView()
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        setupLayout()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
    }
}

private extension MainSecondViewController {
    func setupConfiguration() {
        collectionCardSkins.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        collectionCardSkins.handlerCellDelegate = self
    }
}

This is childred UIView. I don`t can to initialize field "currentMenuItem"
Xcode show two error:

'self' used in property access 'frame' before 'super.init' call
Property 'self.currentMenuItem' not initialized at super.init call

import UIKit

final class SampleSkinsCollectionView: UIView {

    // MARK: - Dependencies
    var handlerCellDelegate: IHandlerCellDelegate?
    var currentMenuItem: MenuItem

    // MARK: - Private properties
    private lazy var collectionCardMaps = createCollectionView()

    private var modelForDisplay: [SkinsModel] = []

    // MARK: - Initializator

    init(currentMenuItem: MenuItem) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.currentMenuItem = currentMenuItem
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        addUIView()
        setupConfiguration()
        setupLayout()
    }

    convenience init(handlerCellDelegate: IHandlerCellDelegate?) {
        self.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
        self.handlerCellDelegate = handlerCellDelegate
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    // MARK: - Public methods
    func reloadModel(viewModel: [SkinsModel]) {
        self.modelForDisplay = viewModel
        collectionCardMaps.reloadData()
    }
}


You can set it up on prepare(for segue:) or in your setupConfiguration(). Change the declaration to var currentMenuItem: MenuItem! for this to work (or var currentMenuItem: MenuItem? but then you need to unwrap it)

Joakim Danielson thanks for your help.

How crooked is this implementation.
We need to implement the method. And throw the field initialization into it? What if I forget about the method?
func reloadCurrentMenuItem(currentMenuItem: MenuItem) {
 self.currentMenuItem = currentMenuItem
 print("currentMenuItem \(currentMenuItem)")
 }


the properties of subclass must be initialized before superclass.
It will look like this:
final class SampleSkinsCollectionView: UIView {

// MARK: - Dependencies
var currentMenuItem: MenuItem

// MARK: - Initializator
init(currentMenuItem: MenuItem) {
    self.currentMenuItem = currentMenuItem
    super.init(frame: .zero)
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

}
you can read more about initialization in Swift documentation
